# Magento 2: Two plugins of LayoutProcessor

Tags: magento2, layout, plugin

We have an extension that has a block class that implements the `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface`

I need to add a custom field in checkout so I created my own plugin of `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor` which works as expected.

But when I create a plugin of the `LayoutProcessor` class of the extension, it doesn't work. I can't see my custom field. But it should work right? As the class extension is implementing the `LayoutProcessorInterface`

Now my question is why is my plugin not working,when the class implements the `LayoutProcessorInterface`?

Answer (score 0):

***Try this format***

> Namespace/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="custom-checkout" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\PluginName" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
</config>
```

> Namespace\Module\Plugin\PluginName.php

```
<?php
namespace Module\Namespace\Plugin;
class PluginName
{
    public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $processor, $jsLayout){

    $test = 'test';

    $newField = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
            'customEntry' => null,
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
            'tooltip' => [
                'description' => 'description'
            ]
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.' . $test,
        'label' => 'Custom Label',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'sortOrder' => 0,
        'validation' => [
            'required-entry' => true
        ],
        'options' => [],
        'filterBy' => null,
        'customEntry' => null,
        'visible' => true
    ];

    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$test2] = $newField;

    return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

### To extend the private method [Event-Observer](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html) should be used